# .htaccess php friendly Urls SEO

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Not sure what is the problem with my .htaccess file or perhaps I do not understand yet how to use it.

As I understand it:

*i can place in href=" " in <a> tag something like

```
    someMeaningfulStuff/post-about-something-here
```

*i can have an .htaccess file in the same directory as the php script that is the actual target of the link which can pick up said url (rewriteRule),
use a regular expression to extract a portion of it

AND

insert it in the actual url where the resource lives while client has on their browser url addres something like:

```
    http://localhost:8080/adminBlog/post-about-something-here
```

eventhough it is actually here:

```
    http://localhost:8080/adminBlog/viewPost.php?id=1
```

Am I wrong?
Here is my files
thanx in advance!

2. the url in index.php(root) to http://localhost:8080/adminBlog/viewPost.php?id=1

   ```
   echo '<h3><a href="/adminBlog/' . $res["postUrl"] . ' " target="_blank" title="link to post" rel="help">' . $res["postTitle"] . '</a></h3>';
   ```

where $res['posturl'] is the response from a query to a database which holds a response in the form:

```
    some-title-to-some-blog-post
```

2. have wamp/apache config:

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```

   ```
   AllowOverride All
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
   ```
3. .htaccess file:

   ```
   Options FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /adminBlog
   RewriteRule ^/?adminBlog/(.+)$ /viewPost.php?id=$1
   ```

5.
in http://localhost:8080/adminBlog/viewPost.php

```
$q = $dbConPDO->prepare('SELECT postId, postTitle, postDesc, postDate, postCont FROM ' .$x. ' WHERE postUrl = :friendlyUrl');
$q->execute(array(':friendlyUrl' => $_GET['id']));
$res = $q->fetch();
```

6.
directory

```
    -c
      -wamp
        -www
          -index.php
          -adminBlog //(this dir is within www as index.php is)
            -.htaccess //(as above in #3)
            -viewpost.php
```

Comment: Can't give you the full answer, but you got to put your `.htaccess` file into `www/` dir and change rewrite base to `/` or remove it, as client will not request `www/adminBlog/`. In your rewrite rule you will need to have something like `^/?(.+)$ /adminBlog/viewPost.php?id=$1`

Comment: I this exactly this but now I get;

[code]  
      Internal Server Error
        The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and         was unable to complete your request.
        Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to         inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you         performed just before this error.
        More information about this error may be available in the server         error log.
        Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 8080

Comment: See: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I was mistakenly reasoning that the .htaccess file had to be in the folder of the target php script that was to handle the data while the referrer was in the root folder.

1.
Referrer (<a href='' >;, in index.php) in root (/) now reads:

```
    echo '<h3><a href="viewPost/' . $res["postUrl"] . '" target="_blank" title="link to post" rel="help">' . $res["postTitle"] . '</a></h3>';
```

2
.htaccess in root now reads:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .+
 RewriteRule ^/?viewPost/(.+)/?$ adminBlog/viewPost.php?id=$1
```

Perhaps the RewriteBase is unnecessary as this file is in root dir.

It was as simple as that!

Thanx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want  `http://localhost:8080/post-about-something-here`, the .htaccess file should be at the root folder. otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: totally makes sence but i still had issues with it.
 Not Found

The requested URL /adminBlog/one-two was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 8080